# PHP hello world, problema estranho

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema estranho em um simples hello world com php, utilizo o XAMPP na última versão, e ao declarar o código mais básico:

```
<?php echo "Hello World" ?>
```

Ao invés do resultado ser um:

Hello World

Tenho:

HelloWorld

E ao aplicar um segundo espaço deixando o código desta forma:

```
<?php echo "Hello  World" ?>
```

O resultado passa a ser:

Hello World

Ou seja, o esperado inicialmente.

Não sei ao certo se é uma falha de configuração ou que seria, estou utilizando o navegador Edge, também na última versão estável disponível.

Comment: Se olhar o código fonte direto do navegador (clicar com direito do mouse), o texto continua junto no primeiro caso?

Comment: Sim, ao analisar os elementos ele está sendo impresso em um <body>HelloWorld</body>, porém na aba "console" ele está saindo como esperado, separado.

Comment: Consegue testar em outro navegador?

Comment: Acabei de baixar o google chrome e efetuar o teste e rodou como o esperado...
Seria um bug do Edge então?

Comment: Talvez apenas a forma como ele tenta renderizar um conteúdo que não seja HTML válido (tanto que ele adicionou as tags `<body>` no código, como você comentou).

Comment: Tente imprimir um "hello world completo". Com  `<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>`.

Comment: Provavelmente é esta questão do HTML válido mesmo, analisei o debugador do EDGE, e tinha a mensagem sobre um erro na leitura do HTML.

Breno, eu sei que existe outras formas de fazer dar certo no edge, mas me intriguei pelo fato desta forma que também é correta não dar certo.

Comment: qual a verão do php ?

Comment: 7.3.5 é a versão utilizada

Comment: testaste no firefox ou chrome?